# Можно ли запустить файл js в отладчике без файлов других типов

Tags: javascript

Я понял, что в отладчике можно проверять веб страницы, но можно ли проверить исключительно написанный js код? Без файлов html и css

Comment: Если ваш скрипт работает с DOM, то нет смысла проверять его отдельно. Однако средства разработчика позволяют дебажить js скрипты

Answer (score 1):

Предположим вы разрабатываете в *Chrome* (рекомендую именно этот браузер), а также js скрипты подключаются в html код через `script src`, тогда можно спокойно открыть инструменты разработчика, открыть вкладку "Sources"  слева можно найти ресурсы сайта, все подключенные скрипты и там поставить брейкпойты и сделать отладку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

В других браузерах примерно такой же подход

---

Но как минимум один html файл создать придётся. Просто так js продебажить вряд ли получится..  Точнее можно в консоли разработчика написать код и поставить `debugger;`  но считаю, что проще создать один файл и подключить туда js, нежели мучиться с консолью браузера